# mysql parameter adds not evaluating

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following code where I am trying to call a mysql stored procedure as I cannot a) get the stored proc to work in EF and b) I cant get the EF LINQ query to work either soooooo I'm going back to older basics. The following errs as VS is asking the line for ExecuteQuery to supply the parameters. Isn't that what I've done already prior to calling that?

```
Public Shared Function GetNearestWeatherStationSql(ByVal lat As Decimal, longi As Decimal) As String
    Const connectionString As String = "server=xxxxxx;user=xxxxxx;database=xxxxxxx;port=xxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand()
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.CommandText = "Call GetNearestWeatherStation()"
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iLat", lat)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iLong", longi)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iWithinMiles", 15)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iTopN", 2)

    command.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conn.Close()


    Return "p"  'bogus value until I get SP to work
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it isnt pretty and anyone can feel to show a suitable refactoring but I added each parameter individually to the collection and then used a reader to access.

```
Public Shared Function GetNearestWeatherStationSql(ByVal lat As Decimal, longi As Decimal) As String
    Const connectionString As String = "xxxxxx"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand()
    command.CommandText = "GetNearestWeatherStation"
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim param As New MySqlParameter()
    With param
        .ParameterName = "@iLat"
        .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Decimal
        .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        .Value = lat
    End With
    command.Parameters.Add(param)
    Dim param1 As New MySqlParameter()
    With param1
        .ParameterName = "@iLong"
        .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Decimal
        .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        .Value = longi
    End With
    command.Parameters.Add(param1)
    Dim param2 As New MySqlParameter()
    With param2
        .ParameterName = "@iWithinMiles"
        .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32
        .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        .Value = 15
    End With
    command.Parameters.Add(param2)
    Dim param3 As New MySqlParameter()
    With param3
        .ParameterName = "@iTopN"
        .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32
        .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        .Value = 2
    End With
    command.Parameters.Add(param3)
    command.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Dim stationlist As New List(Of String)
    If reader.HasRows() Then
        While reader.Read()
            stationlist.Add(reader("station_id").ToString())
        End While
    End If
    conn.Close()

    Return stationlist(0)  'bogus value until I get SP to work
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddWithValue` provides substitutions for the named placeholders. But you didn't put the placeholders in the query.

```
command.CommandText = "Call GetNearestWeatherStation(@iLat, @iLong, @iWithinMiles, @iTopN)"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iLat", lat)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iLong", longi)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iWithinMiles", 15)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iTopN", 2)
```

Comment: Doing so now gives a "Procedure or Function not found in database"